# Align button element to bottom of div in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a php page that pulls data from a mysql database and generates a bootstrap grid based on the database content, fairly standard stuff.  I have a title, icon, description and link that i need to output into a grid 3 wide

The short of the code is this

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
  <h2 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h2>
  <img src="<?php echo $row['icon']; ?>" width="64" height="64" class="icons">
  <p><?php echo $row['description'] ?></p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" href="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>" target="_blank">Download <?php echo $row['title'] ?></a></p>
 </div>
```

As the description can be 2 lines or 20 lines long what i would love to be able to do is align the button to the bottom of the div based on the longest description in that row.

I found a few options but they all involved manually setting the height on the class, which just looked odd for those rows that had shorter descriptions than others.  It also screwed up the responsive design which is the ultimate goal for the site

I'm assuming i would have to use jQuery mixed with some CSS to do this, but struggling to work out the best way.

Site is an internal site so i can't directly link to the entire site, but happy to provide more code snippets if needed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use relative positioning for the button like:

```
p a.btn {
  position: relative;
  bottom:5px;
}
```

Not tested but may be it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but doesn't align the button to the bottom of the div.   My thoughts are to use jQuery to get the height of the heighest column, set the other 2 to the same height then use somehting like 
`.bottomaligned {position:absolute; bottom:0;  margin-bottom:7px; left: 0;}`
to set the button to sit at the absolute bottom the column
If i use the above CSS code it does work, but i need to set a height of the Div - and this is what messes up my design, by using jQuery I was hoping for something a little more streamlined